# Change deploy root on gitlab Pages

Tags: git, deployment, gitlab, gitlab-pages

I've been creating gitlab pages with the `.gitlab-ci.yml` template file:

```
# This file is a template, and might need editing before it works on your project.
# Full project: https://gitlab.com/user/project
pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - mkdir .public
  - cp -r * .public
  - mv .public public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

So far so good, it runs the index.html file on repo root.

**The problem:** I have a repo where the production files are on `dist/` folder.

How do I change the deploy to read the files on that folder instead of reading the root ?

**tree**

```
- /src
- /dist 
---- index.html ---> i want to set this as root
---- assets/ 
.gitignore
README.md
gulpfile.js
package.json

----> gitlab is trying to find index.html on the root
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant do it directly but you can use the following trick/hack:

`html` has the following meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://repo.github.io/folder/index.html" />
```

commit this as your index.html and it will redirect the index page to any inner file you want inside your local `gh-pages` branch.

The `http-equiv="refresh"` will redirect the page to any desired location you want.